# `fgetpos` Not Returning the Correct Position

Tags: c++, fgetpos

*Update: To get around the problem below, I have done*

```
if (ftell(m_pFile) != m_strLine.size())
    fseek(m_pFile, m_strLine.size(), SEEK_SET);
fpos_t position;
fgetpos(m_pFile, &position);
```

*this then returns the correct position for my file. However, I would still like to understand why this is occurring?*

---

I want to get the position in a text file. For most files I have been reading the first line, storing the position, doing some other stuff and returning to the position afterwards...

```
m_pFile = Utils::OpenFile(m_strBaseDir + "\\" + Source + "\\" + m_strFile, "r");
m_strLine = Utils::ReadLine(m_pFile);
bEOF = feof(m_pFile) != 0;
if (bEOF)
{
    Utils::CompilerError(m_ErrorCallback, 
        (boost::format("File '%1%' is empty.") % m_strFile).str());
    return false;
}

// Open.
pFileCode = Utils::OpenFile(strGenCode + "\\" + m_strFile, options.c_str());
m_strLine = Utils::Trim(m_strLine);
Utils::WriteLine(pFileCode, m_strLine);

// Store location and start passes.
unsigned int nLineCount = 1;
fpos_t position;
fgetpos(m_pFile, &position);
m_strLine = Utils::ReadLine(m_pFile);
...
fsetpos(m_pFile, &position);
m_strLine = Utils::ReadLine(m_pFile);
```

With all files provided to me the storage of the `fgetpos` and `fsetpos` works correctly. The problem is with a file that I have created which looks like

[image: EG]

which is almost identical to the supplied files. The problem is that for the file above `fgetpos(m_pFile, &position);` is not returning the correct `position` (I am aware that the `fpos_t position` is implementation specific). After the first `ReadLine` I get a `position` of 58 (*edited from 60*) so that when I attempt to read the second line with

```
fsetpos(m_pFile, &position);
m_strLine = Utils::ReadLine(m_pFile);
```

I get

> on 700

instead of

> Selection: Function ADJEXCL

**Why is `fgetpos` not returning the position of the end of the first line?**

---

_Note. The `Utils.ReadLine` method is:

```
std::string Utils::ReadLine(FILE* file)
{
   if (file == NULL)
      return NULL;
   char buffer[MAX_READLINE];
   if (fgets(buffer, MAX_READLINE, file) != NULL)
   {
      if (buffer != NULL)
      {
         std::string str(buffer);
         Utils::TrimNewLineChar(str);
         return str;
      }
   }
   std::string str(buffer);
   str.clear();
   return str;
}
```

with

```
void Utils::TrimNewLineChar(std::string& s)
{
   if (!s.empty() && s[s.length() - 1] == '\n') 
      s.erase(s.length() - 1);
}
```

---

*Edit. Following the debugging suggestions in the comments I have added the following code*

```
m_pFile = Utils::OpenFile(m_strBaseDir + "\\" + Source + "\\" + m_strFile, "r");
m_strLine = Utils::ReadLine(m_pFile); 
// Here m-strLine = "          Logic Definition Report Chart Version: New Version 700" (64 chars).
long vv = ftell(m_pFile); // Here vv = 58!?

fpos_t pos;
vv = ftell(m_pFile);
fgetpos(m_pFile, &pos); // pos = 58.
fsetpos(m_pFile, &pos);
m_strLine = Utils::ReadLine(m_pFile);
```

Comment: I think there's a bit missing between "a file that I have created which looks like" and "which is almost identical". That said, on Windows you need to beware of newline conversion when you read in text mode, and that might be your problem.

Comment: Thanks for that, I have edited the question. The text file was created with C# and uses the default encoding (`Encoding.Default`) to write the text file. The line endings used are `\r\n` and seem to show up exactly the same for the files that do work. I am lost as to why this (the file that I created) is the only one out of 40 that fails to return the correct position using the above code!? The carrage returns and line breaks look right!?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15649089/2065121) is possibly related (not sure if it's a dupe though).

Comment: Can you try to call fgetpos() and immediately call fsetpos() and ReadLine()? If this works must be sth in the job in between that changed position.

Comment: Also, use ftell() to debug

Comment: @Sheen I have attempted what you suggested and the same thing occurs. That is, I call `ReadLine`, `fgetpos` (this returns the erroneous value), `fsetpos` and `ReadLine`. Read line reads the remainder of the first line!?

Comment: @Killercam Can you try to output value of ftell() after fgetpos and fsetpos?

Comment: @Sheen I have edited the question with the suggested debugging...

Comment: @Killercam Can you insert "vv = ftell(m_pFile);" line after "fsetpos(m_pFile, &pos);" and check value of vv then?

Comment: @Sheen I will do this now. See the other edit for what I have done to get around this - I would still like to know what the hell is going on!? Thanks very much for your help and time here!

Comment: Again, this is 58 as you would expect here... @Kaz I agree, this is a strange one.

Comment: If the 58 is expected, it must be that the position is 1 based and not zero based, since the line is 57 bytes long.   A value of 60 up from 58 would occur if there is a two byte BOM (byte order marker) at the beginning of the file.

Comment: The file handle passed to `fgetpos` and `fsetpos` are the saem, right?  You haven't reopened the file or anything like that?

Comment: @BenVoigt Nah nah, of course not. My C++ isn't the best but I am not a compete knob.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but your Utils functions have clearly been written by an incompetent.  Some issues are just a matter of style.  For trimming:

```
void Utils::TrimNewLineChar(std::string& s)
{
   if (!s.empty() && *s.rbegin() == '\n') 
      s.resize(s.size() - 1); // resize, not erase
}
```

or in C++11

```
void Utils::TrimNewLineChar(std::string& s)
{
   if (!s.empty() && s.back() == '\n') 
      s.pop_back();
}
```

`ReadLine` is even worse, replace it with:

```
std::string Utils::ReadLine(FILE* file)
{
   std::string str;
   char buffer[MAX_READLINE];
   if (file != NULL && fgets(buffer, MAX_READLINE, file) != NULL)
   {
      // it is guaranteed that buffer != NULL, since it is an automatic array
      str.assign(buffer);
      Utils::TrimNewLineChar(str);
   }
   // copying buffer into str is useless here
   return str;
}
```

That last `str(buffer)` in the original worries me especially.  If `fgets` reaches a newline, fills the buffer, or reaches end of file, you're guaranteed to get a properly terminated string in your buffer.  If some other I/O error occurs?  Who knows?  It might be undefined behavior.

Best not to rely on the value of `buffer` when `fgets` fails.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I will attempt these updates and get back to you... The 'incompetent' is myself. I have been coding in C/C++ for about 4 weeks in total, so apologies.

Comment: Despite the nice rewrites of the code I provided, this did not help the problem of the erroneous `fgetpos` result...

Comment: @ Killercam: That would certainly explain it. Your competence will grow with experience, although I wonder what resources you are learning from that led to these mistakes.  I'm not sure what is causing the weird file positioning behavior, if not undefined behavior in the code. Probably stepping through library code with a debugger is the most direct path to understanding that.

Comment: Ben, cheers for the help, your time is most appreciated. I just have a basic C++ book; I work alone and in isolation, so help from more senior guys is non-existent. That is why this site and people like yourself are so valuable to me. I will look at stepping through the library stuff tomorrow, but I have wasted enough time on this and have a hack that fixes it - I might just leave it there (danger). Again, thanks - all the best...

Comment: @Killercam: You might check out the SO Guide to C++ Books: http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242