# Are fgetpos() and fsetpos() only for text mode? What location/offset data is the fpos_t object filled with if not number of bytes?

Tags: c, fseek, ftell, fgetpos

I understand the workings of ftell() and fseek() in C, but for this question I couldn't find any precise answer anywhere, including from the closest post on StackOverflow([LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348637/fgetpos-fsetpos-and-ftell-fseek)).

So can you please answer the following:

- Can it be concluded that fgetpos() and fsetpos() are relevant only for text files opened in text mode, and not for files opened in binary mode?
- What kind of position information is the fpos_t object filled with by fgetpos(), given that it is not a long integer offset etc. like the one given by ftell()? The site **cplusplusreference** only tells the following:

> The function fills the fpos_t object pointed by pos with the information needed from the stream's position indicator to restore the stream to its current position

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`fgetpos()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgetpos/?kw=fgetpos) and [`fsetpos()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fsetpos/) are relevant for both text and binary mode.

The advantage of `fgetpos()` is that is keeps the full position in the stream, including its internal **state**,  so that you can restore is later.  This works whether you are in text mode or not.  This is especially important if you are using [wide oriented streams](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa241851%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) or mix `fgetc()` and [`fgetwc()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/fgetwc/) in the same file, because some locale use a state dependent multibyte encoding (state depends on previous reads).

[`fseek()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/) and `ftell()` can also work with text and binary mode.  However there is an important restriction in text mode: you should only use `fseek()` with 0 or a value previously returned by `ftell()` (in binary mode you can use whatever value you want). This is because the text mode reading can change the number of bytes returned from  reading compared to the bytes effectively in the file (typical example, the 2 CR+LF bytes in a windows file which are converted to a signe LF byte).

As `ftell()` only returns a `long int` offset, it can't keep track of the multibyte state if this would be needed. So using `fseek()` might loose this state.

Comment: I grasped most of your answer. But the first line is something new to me. Can you please provide a short compilable sample program where fgetpos() and fsetpos() are used in binary mode? Else can you provide a link where I can read more?

Comment: @Meathead: if you have a code sample where they're used in text mode, then you can produce for yourself an example where they're used in binary mode simply by changing the more the file is opened. The two functions are defined to do what they do, whichever mode the file is opened.

Comment: @SteveJessop Thanks. I'll do it. In any case, your confirmation is as good for me as testing it myself :-)

Comment: You cannot portably mix byte-oriented and wide-oriented operations on the same stream. Otherwise, +1

Answer (score 2):

Not quite. Clues can be found from [Beej](http://beej.us/guide/bgc/output/html/multipage/fgetpos.html):

> On virtually every system (and certainly every system that I know of),
>   people don't use these functions, using ftell() and fseek() instead.
>   These functions exist just in case your system can't remember file
>   positions as a simple byte offset.

And [Linux man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgetpos):

> On some non-UNIX systems, an fpos_t object may be a complex object and
>   these routines may be the only way to portably reposition a text
>   stream.

And on [Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15649089/fgetpos-behaviour-depends-on-newline-character):

> It assumes that any \n character in the buffer was originally a \r\n
>   sequence that had been normalized when the data was read into the
>   buffer.

That is to say, files that aren't (Windows-linebreak) text files go wrong in Windows when opened in text mode because `fsetpos` is assuming the file really was a (Windows-linebreak) text file and therefore cannot contain a `\n` with no `\r`.

The C11 standard says (my emphasis):

7.21.2/6:

> Each **wide-oriented** stream has an associated mbstate_t object that
>   stores the current parse state of the stream.  A successful call to
>   fgetpos stores a representation of the value of this mbstate_t object
>   as part of the value of the fpos_t object. A  later successful call to
>   fsetpos using the same stored fpos_t value restores the value of the
>   associated mbstate_t object as well as the position within the
>   controlled stream.

Note that `fseek` and `ftell` have nothing to say about the `mbstate_t` object: they do not report or restore it. So on wide-oriented streams (that is to say, streams on which you've used wide-oriented I/O functions) they only reset the file position, not (if the implementation actually has more than one possible value of a `mbstate_t` object) the whole state of the stream.

Wide-oriented streams aren't the same thing as text streams, it's just that reading wide text files is the common use for them. Actually `fseek` and `ftell` are documented to be able to reset the file position on text files, provided you use them correctly. So I believe (I might be wrong) that `fsetpos` and `fgetpos` are only required when using wide I/O functions on the stream.

Comment: Thanks for the details, more so as it answers the second part of my question. But can you please explain, as mentioned in the other answer, how fgetpos() and fsetpos() can be used in binary mode as well? Can I use fgetpos() to find position indicator in a binary file and use the information on fsetpos() just as in text files? No difference?

Comment: @Meathead: no difference. It's just that since (on systems where there's any difference at all between binary and text mode) you wouldn't normally use the wide I/O functions on a binary file, there's no benefit to using `fgetpos` over using `fseek`. On Posix systems, where text and binary modes are defined to be the same, you might well use wide-oriented binary files but (if I understand correctly, it's been a while since any of this mattered to me), Posix doesn't allow stateful encodings as the system wide character mode and so there's nothing to restore.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the reasons mentioned in the other answers, it might be necessary to use `fgetpos` and `fsetpos` if you are working with *very large* files, files that contain more than `LONG_MAX` bytes.  This is a real concern on systems where `LONG_MAX` is 2<sup>31</sup> − 1; files with more than two billion bytes in them are not that uncommon nowadays.

If you are on a system that implements POSIX.1-2001, there is a better alternative, which is to `#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64` before including any system header files, and then use [`fseeko` and `ftello`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fseeko.3.html). These are just like `fseek` and `ftell` except that they take/return an `off_t` quantity, which, provided you have made the above `#define`, is guaranteed to be an integer type that can represent 2<sup>63</sup> − 1, which ought to be enough for anybody.  This is better because you can do arithmetic on `off_t`; you can't use `fpos_t` to go somewhere you haven't already been.  But if you're not on a POSIX system, `fgetpos` and `fsetpos` might be your only option.

(Note that some systems will give you an `fpos_t` that *can't* represent a file offset greater than `LONG_MAX` bytes. On some of those, applying the same `#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64` setting will help.  On others, you're just completely out of luck if you want a huge file.)